# How to calculate CAT-Bond Profit

Tags: bond-yields, insurance, profit

I understand that a CAT Bond is supposed to be a high risk and high return for the investor and a risk transfer for insurer. But as the sponsor (the issuer of the bond), how can one calculate the profit ?

Comment: the issuer of the bond